# Auto Populate To Field - Reply to Email2Case

Tags: email, email2case

I have implemented email-to-case. The new case can be opened in Service Console tab. Now when i am trying to email from the service console, I would like to have To field auto populated with the email address from where the initial email came and case got created.

Do you have any idea how can I auto populate the To field? Any help here is highly appreciated? Thanks.

Regards,
Sudipta Deb

Answer (score 2):

Email2Case will automatically populate a field on the case record called Web Email (From memory the developername for this is SuppliedEmail)

When you send an email from the Case using the Service Console Email Publisher, Salesforce first looks to see if a contact record is associated and if so will auto populate the To field with the contacts email address (as stored in Contact.Email).

If there is no Contact associated, then the case will automatically populate with the Web Email address.

If this isn't happening, first place to check should be field level security and page layouts to make sure the Web Email field is accessible.

Unfortunately I have found the web email behaviour isn't 100% foolproof, the best approach is to make sure that there is an associated contact with an email.

Comment: one additional bit, not directly relevant to OP: if I recall, if there are multiple Contacts with the same email address, SFDC will not populate the Case ContactId field

Comment: Good point!  I can't recall if that's because it doesn't associate the case to a contact in the first place in that scenario?

Comment: yes, my notes in Apex code indicate that SFDC can't decide which Contact to use to set Case.ContactId if there are more than one Contact for same email address

Comment: I guess you could write a  before insert trigger on the case to look for situations where web email isn't blank but contactid is.  But deciding which contact to use would be the challenge - the most recent one, the one with the most acitivities, the one with a "primary" flag...  I guess a task could be added to the case to have an agent manually select and add the correct contact - that could probably be achieved with workflow or process builder

Comment: we're getting off topic here but I constructed Contacts from `suppliedEmail` where `contactId` was null, one also has to derive, if possible, `case.acccountId` - bottom line, my support reps were trained to create Contacts/Accounts when it wasn't possible to derive from existing Accounts and Contacts.

Comment: I have the contacts mentioned in the case and that contact is having an email address also. Still the To Field is not getting auto populated. The field accessibility is Editable for WebEmail field

Comment: Strange - are you creating the email using the case feed email publisher?  I'm not sure that it will auto populate from the activity history "send an email" button.  If you're trying to do that you might be able to create a custom button with a URL hack to populate the to field.

Answer (score 0):

Did anyone find a solution to this problem? In my case there are three email messages that exist for a case - if i click in on the first EmailMessage in the email related list the To field is not populated -  but strangely in case of the other two the To field is populated with the Case.Contact Email address ... why? I want the standard reply link/button to function correctly - why the difference?

[image: Email Messages - related list on case]